# instance variable output showing #<Goal:0x007fd4734aa818>in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, function, variables

I have this code in my app

```
 current_general_goal = @current_user.goals.sum(:general_goal)     
 @general_goal =  current_general_goal.nil? ? 0 : current_general_goal
```

It gives me the `sum`of  the `general_goal` for the current user

I changed the code to this to see the last `general_goal`by current_user

```
  current_general_goal = @current_user.goals(:general_goal).last   
  @general_goal =  (current_general_goal.nil? ? 0 : current_general_goal)
```

But then the output in the view shows `#<Goal:0x007fd4734aa818>`

Why is that? google doesn't seems to know why, can someone explain that to me?

Comment: did you get it solved?

Answer (score 0):

```
@current_user.goals(:general_goal).last.to_s
```

will return you

```
#<Goal:0x007fd4734aa818>
```

Meaning, that you are getting the object's string representation, not it's attribute.

Changing `@current_user.goals(:general_goal).last` to `@current_user.goals(:general_goal).last.SOME_ATTRIBUTE` will result in what you need.